# Visual studio evaluates func in debugger before it is called

Tags: c#, debugging, lazy-loading, func

I want to implement custom `Lazy<T>` class, just to implement it. What is interesting is that when I pass function to constructor, in debugger I can already see that the object has been created inside the function even though the actual call is inside `Value`. Is this because debugger evaluates the `_func` itself or do I just don't understand how `Func<>` works?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var lazyObj = new LazyTest<Entity>(() => new Entity { Foo = 5 }); // Debugger shows that Entity is already created here and Foo = 5.
        var entity = lazyObj.Value; // Creation of Entity should happen here.
        Console.WriteLine(entity.Foo);

        Console.Read();
    }
}

public class Entity
{
    public int Foo { get; set; }
}

public class LazyTest<T>
{
    private T _value;
    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            if (_value == null)
                _value = _func();
            return _value;
        }
    }
    private Func<T> _func { get; set; }

    public LazyTest(Func<T> func)
    {
        _func = func;
    }
```

I found that `Lazy<T>` internally uses property `internal T ValueForDebugDisplay`, but I'm not 100% sure if this is an answer to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add a breakpoint, the debugger is showing you values of variables and properties existing in current scope. It's by default evaluating them, you can approach this behaviour in a couple of ways:

1) Add the DebuggerBrowsable Never attribute to your property, then it's value is not going to be shown in the locals window:

[DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]

2) Disable this behaviour in Visual Studio: Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General -> and there disable  **"Enable property evaluation...**"

3) [Look how Lazy does it](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/Lazy.cs). We see the attributes added to the class:

```
[DebuggerDisplay("ThreadSafetyMode={Mode}, IsValueCreated={IsValueCreated}, IsValueFaulted={IsValueFaulted}, Value={ValueForDebugDisplay}")]
public class Lazy<T>
```

The property you mentioned, ValueForDebugDisplay, is implemented here:

```
internal T ValueForDebugDisplay
{
    get
    {
        if (!IsValueCreated)
        {
             return default(T);
        }
        return ((Boxed)m_boxed).m_value;
    }
}
```

As you can see, it the value is not created yet, it's showing the default value of the Lazy generic type.

Comment: But does my current implementation actually create the object or does the debugger create it for the purpose of showing it? When does the memory get allocated for the object? Before calling `Value` or after?

Comment: The debugger is creating it to show it to you in Locals window. It happens when the debugger hits the breakpoint, I've added some ways of approaching this problem above, good luck :)

Comment: Actually, you are right. I inserted a `Console.WriteLine`, to see when it gets printed and turns out it gets printed either when I call `Value` or I look at the `Value` in debugger.